# Why is LPF amplifies the baseband signal?

Tags: lowpass-filter, audio-processing

I am working with a PDM digital microphone and I've sampled the data using a FPGA.
For the beginning I am working in python to do all the algorithm, then I will implement it in FPGA.
I am using two LPF filters using firwin and remez functions for testing by now, and as far I understand the audio baseband pass without amplification, and the rest spectrum is attenuated. but Why the audio baseband does look like amplified? or there something that I am missing?

here is the [data1.csv](https://mega.nz/file/rgwHiT7R#SxZaE7yGvj2MLAJIbjA9GGE8uXqCUTrrrbYzKQ61DO4)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import csv
import pandas


num_taps = 60 # 
cutoff = 40.0e3    # Desired cutoff frequency, Hz
trans_width = 150e3 
fs = 2.38e6 # Hz

# Create low pass filter
h = signal.firwin(num_taps, cutoff, nyq=fs/2)

# Parks-McClellan algorithm
hn = signal.remez(  num_taps,
                    [0, cutoff, cutoff+trans_width, fs/2.0],
                    [1, 0], # loss pass filter
                    Hz=fs, # sampling frequency
                    )


# Reading microphone PDM 
filename = 'data1.csv'
data_in = pandas.read_csv(filename)    
tiempo = data_in['time']
dato_pd = data_in['data']
dato = dato_pd.to_numpy()
dato = dato.astype(np.float)

data_length = 1000
datos = dato[0:data_length]
tim = np.arange(0, data_length)*1.0/fs

# Filtered data
y_remez=signal.lfilter(hn,1,datos)
y_fir=signal.lfilter(h,1,datos)

# Filtered data in frequency domain
mag1 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(datos, 1024)) # 1024 pints FFT and magnitude
mag1 = np.fft.fftshift(mag1) 
w1 = np.linspace(-fs/2, fs/2, len(mag1))

mag2 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(y_remez, 1024)) # 1024 pints FFT and magnitude
mag2 = np.fft.fftshift(mag2) 

mag3 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(y_fir, 1024)) # 1024 pints FFT and magnitude
mag3 = np.fft.fftshift(mag3)
            
# Plot results

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
#   Plot Filtered PDM data 
axs[0].plot(tim, datos, label="Data")
axs[0].plot(tim, y_remez, label="Remez")
axs[0].plot(tim, y_fir, label="firwin")
axs[0].set_title("PDM Microphone data")
axs[0].legend(shadow=True, loc='upper right')

#   Plot Frequency response of filters
w,Hn = signal.freqz(hn, 1)  
axs[1].plot(w/np.pi*(fs/2)/1000.0,20*np.log10(abs(Hn)),label='Remez') 
w,H = signal.freqz(h, 1)  
axs[1].plot(w/np.pi*(fs/2)/1000.0,20*np.log10(abs(H)),label='firwin') 
axs[1].set_xlabel('KHz')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Gain(dB)')
axs[1].set_title('Filter frequency response')
axs[1].legend(shadow=True, loc='upper right')

#   Plot spectrum of filtered data
axs[2].plot(w1/1000.0,mag1,label='not filtered') 
axs[2].plot(w1/1000.0,mag2,label='Remez') 
axs[2].plot(w1/1000.0,mag3,label='firwin') 
axs[2].set_xlabel('KHz')
axs[2].set_title('Spectrum')
axs[2].legend(shadow=True, loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing where it is amplified in the plot.  It looks like the line for unfiltered is just under the filtered version.  Can you provide more guidance for what you think is happening?

Comment: sorry if it is a extremly basic question, why the not filtered signal (blue line) appear in the center frequency with a higher amplitude after it is filtered ?

Comment: @arlen Since all of those results are plotted on top of the previous one, you may not able to see the blue and orange spikes which are below the green.

Comment: I uploaded a picture that shows why i am confused

Comment: It's not a basic question. It's actually a very good one. Note that your "center frequency" is your DC component. Try removing the mean before filtering and note the difference. `datos = datos - np.mean(datos)`. That's not all that's happening here (you should also try increasing `data_length` to `len(dato)` and use `data_length` instead of 1024 for the fft computations), but that's a start. I'll try to give you a better answer that actually explains what you're seeing when I have time. Hopefully some of the experts here get to it before I do ;)

Comment: @Jdip i did wht you suggested, i am more confused. where is that peak from?, It near to 
 the Nyquist frequency, I hope someone can help to understand what monster I've created :')